# crud edit button modal variable is undefined

Tags: php, html, mysqli, crud

I am creating my first php app and running into an issue on how I should try and edit a sql entry.  I was planning on trying to get a modal window to pop up in order to edit.

When I select the edit link to open the modal window the variable says it is undefined.  I am thinking it is because the Modal and variable are added to DOM before I click the link to edit and the variable never gets set.    How do I get around this?

```
<?php            

$sql = "SELECT id, image, name, score, points FROM teams";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {



    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $teams_id = $row["id"];
        $teams_image = $row["image"];
        $teams_name = $row["name"];
        $teams_score = $row["score"];
        $teams_points = $row["points"];

    //    echo "id: " . $teams_id . " image path: " . $teams_image . " name: " . $teams_name . " score " . $teams_score . " points " . $teams_points . "</br>"; 
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='row oval'>";
        echo "<div class='col-4 flag {$teams_image}'>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='col-8 text'>";
        echo "<p>{$teams_name}</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";


        // edit and delete button 
        echo "<a href='add_teams_working.php?edit={$teams_id}' class='btn btn-outline-light btn-sm ml-4 align-self-center' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editModal'>edit</a>";
        echo "<button class='btn btn-outline-light btn-sm ml-1 align-self-center'>delete</button>";
        echo "</div>";

    } 
}else {
    echo "No teams added yet";
}
?>   




<!-- SET VARIABLE for MODAL  -->

<?php 
if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $edit_id = $_GET['edit'];



    $query = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id = $edit_id ";
    $select_team = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_team)) {
        $edit_id = $row['id'];
        $edit_image = $row['image'];
        $edit_name = $row['name'];


    }

}
?>
```

Here is modal if needed.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Edit <?php echo $edit_name; ?> </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <?php echo $edit_name; ?>
            <?php echo $edit_image; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, i recommend to escape php, example: <?php PHP_CODE ?> HTML_CODE <?php PHP_CODE ?> to avoid to many echos.
And yes, your IDs should be unique.

Comment: Your modal should have an id attribute, also same value should be used in data-toggle attribute of button

Comment: i have edited the question a bit  and still looking for help.

Comment: In HTML part should be one more closing `</div>`.

Comment: I count 4 opening divs and 4 closing divs.    But I am wondering about adding variable to modal.

Once I click the edit button and the modal window shows up..... I get an error that the variable  "edit_name" is undefined.

Comment: 6 open and only 5 closing tags (div).

Comment: if you are referring to modal..  I have added a closing div.

Comment: OK, then keep in mind that if you do not want to use javascript, you need one modal for each button, with unique id.

Comment: I finally figured out what to search for in google.     "Add dynamic content to Modal".  This search gave me info I needed